# Django Model: Property with Referenced Foreign Keys Does not appear in ListApiView

Tags: django-models, django-views

I am stumbling on this for days and I cannot get it to work. I have a model Hotel that has a one-to-many reference to the Trip model:

```
models.py

class Hotel(models.Model):
    # Relate the hotel service to its Trip
    trip = models.ForeignKey(Trip, related_name='hotels', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Trip(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True, help_text="The name of the trip",)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.title)
```

This means that each trip should have a list with hotels and each hotel should belong to only one trip. I am using "hotels" as a related name in the Hotel object, which means that the trip object should automatically have a property "hotels". Now, I am trying to get all the trips with their corresponding properties to the frontend:

```
views.py

class TripList(generics.ListAPIView):
   """
   A list of all trips, read-only
   """
   # queryset = Trip.objects.all()
   serializer_class = TripSerializer
   queryset = Trip.objects.all()
```

I am able to get the hotels by a given trip using Django template engine but I am using react for frontend and in the ListApiView the hotels property is missing from the trip object. How can I get to update the data in ListApiView?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem appeared to be the data serialization. I was using fields = '**all**' to serialize all the fields in the Trip model:

```
fields = '__all__'
```

However, it is not working like this for data that is passed via related name method. All i had to do is replace the above code with:

```
serializers.py
class TripSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Trip
        depth = 1
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'duration_days', 'hotels')
```

After that, the ListApiView finally showed the trip model with a property "hotels"